# Can any radio flash triggers be used without a sync cable?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, wireless-flash, wireless-triggers

I am looking for an inexpensive wireless flash trigger system to use with my Pentax k-x and an old flash I wouldn't trust on the camera hot shoe (Vivitar 550FD) because of its high trigger voltage. I see that the [CowboyStudio NPT-04](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002W3IXZW) wireless trigger can connect to a camera via a sync cable, perhapts *in place of* **or** *in addition to* using the hot shoe contacts. My camera does not support the use of a sync cable.

**Can radio flash triggers be connected using a camera's hot shoe contacts without requiring the use of a sync cable?**

Comment: They all should. If they can mount to your hot shoe, they should receive the sync info from the hot shoe, and not require any sync cord.

Comment: Thanks everyone for clearing that up. I was a little distrustful of the Amazon description, as those have been wrong before on cheap photography gear. I will edit the question to better help future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CowboyStudio NPT-04 trigger connects to the camera via hotshoe *or* sync cable, you do not need both, just one of them. I have it and have always used it hotshoe mounted.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Amazon "Product Description" more closely, the trigger is hotshoe mounted, so it will work without the need for the sync cable. In any event, if you don't want to get that one, the [Cactus triggers](http://www.gadgetinfinity.com/wireless-trigger/) work as well. I use those with my K-5 and Alien Bees and have never had a problem (nor had to use the PC cable, though the K-5 can use one).

Answer (score 2):

Almost all wireless triggers I am aware of work with hot shoes.

- Phottix:  Atlas, Strato
- Pocket Wizard
- Cactus
- Yongnuo - RF-602, RF-603
- RadioPopper JrX

I know some of these (Phottix, Yongnuo) are compatible with Pentax, but you'd need to research each model to be sure.

Comment: RF-602 and RF-603 have a sync voltage limit of 11V--might not be ideal for a suspected high-voltage flash--RF-603 II's limit is 300V, and doesn't have the Rx/Tx switch issue the original 603s have.